# window ethereum networkVersion undefined

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am developing a frontend of my smart contract using Angular 8 and web3 version `1.2.7`.
When I enter the view my web3 service gets created. In the constructor I check if the `window.ethereum` object exists. If yes I want to set some variables according to the networkVersion, but sometimes networkVersion is undefined and the behavior of the website is then undefined too.

I have no idea why `window.ethereum` exists but networkVersion is undefined. Maybe I call it to early before the provider (in my case Metamask) can set the values.

Does anyone face the same problem and has a solution for that?

**Web3Service.ts**

```
constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar, private dialog: MatDialog) {
   if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      this.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
      // Here networkVersion sometimes undefined
      this.networkId = +window.ethereum.networkVersion;

      if (this.networkId === 1) {
        this.apiPath = environment.apiPathMainnet;
        this.tokenContract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(artifacts.abi, environment.mainnetContractAddress);
      } else if (this.networkId === 3) {
        this.apiPath = environment.apiPathRopsten;
        this.tokenContract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(artifacts.abi, environment.ropstenContractAddress);
      } else {
        this.apiPath = environment.apiPathRopsten;
        this.networkNotSupported();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have the access to the user's MetaMask and therefore the networkVersion, since there is no network provided yet.

have you enabled the MetaMask? you first need to get the user's authentication in order to use his/her MetaMask, using this code `ethereum.enable();` , for further information visit MetaMask documentation in [here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations)

In this case you have "window.ethereum" because the user has the newest version of the MetaMask but don't have the access to user's MetaMask yet.

If the User only has "window.web3" it means he/she has the older version of MetaMask which accessing it doesn't need to be authorized.

[Here](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8) is a post by MetaMask itself on 'medium', explaining this.

Comment: The networkVersion is still available although I am not logged in with `ethereum.enable();` . The version is not available immediately, but after a few milliseconds and that's my issue.

Comment: To handle that you can edit your code with javascript somehow. for example don't let the page load before networkVersion is available. or add javascript code to show a loading icon then reload the page right after the networkVersion is available.

Answer (score 1):

I found `web3.eth.net.getId()` to be more accurate and cross compatible with other wallets. Check out the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-net.html#getid)